# How to add plugin in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, hummingbird

I want to add any plugin to my flutter web project but I am getting an error after adding the plugin. I have run flutter pub get it gave me code 0. But when I try:

```dart
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

It says package not found.

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_daemon: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.6.6
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
  pedantic: ^1.7.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Comment: Can you post you **pubspec.yaml**  file ?

Comment: did you check whether this package is supported for Flutter web

Comment: I have seen someone using the same plugin and it is not working on my end.

Comment: @RSSingh Could you link to where you saw someone using it? I'm willing to bet they were using it in Flutter (for mobile), not Flutter Web (for websites).

Comment: http://mtechviral.com/myportfolio/#/
He is using the same particle plugin for flutter and when I tried it did not work for me. This website is made with flutter for the web.

Comment: @RSSingh Have a look at the repository [here](https://github.com/iampawan/myportfolio/tree/master/web/assets). He *does not* use the same plugin. He adds assets, fonts, etc. through the **web** directory.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the `font_awesome_flutter` plugin yet. It needs to be in your **pubspec.yaml** file like this:

```
environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_daemon: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.6.6
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
  pedantic: ^1.7.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Unfortunately, even if you *did* have it in there, it still wouldn't work as the `font_awesome_flutter` plugin isn't even supported yet for Flutter Web. See the [custom_fonts example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/tree/master/examples/custom_fonts) in the Flutter Web repository for an example of how to add custom fonts on Flutter Web.

Comment: I tried that also but it was not working.After adding "get dependencies", it was totally fine but when I tried to import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart'; It says not found.

Comment: @RSSingh Seriously. Look at the last paragraph in my answer. You have all you need to get Font Awesome working yourself.

Comment: if it is not possible then how sample web projects are using particle_background plugin for web. https://flutter.github.io/samples/particle_background/#/

Comment: I have seen some examples using plugins but none of them are showing there code.I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

> Update: The following instructions are not valid anymore. As the former project repository is archived.

In this particular portfolio site I am not sure if he used any fontawesome plugin. you can check his code here. https://github.com/iampawan/myportfolio

Instead Check this [migration guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/docs/migration_guide.md) to see if you followed these steps mentioned under these sections.

Additionally to use a new plugin this is what I follow in my project. For instance this i how I use graphql-2.1.0 package in my project.

1. I go to the flutter package's version page. In this case [here](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter/versions).
2. Download the latest version and unpack it into a folder in my
   project. eg

   - > $project_dir\packages
   - > along side -- $project_dir\lib, $project_dir\web
3. Replace all the imports inside the $project_dir\packages\font-awesome-folder\lib with

   - > `package:flutter to package:flutter_web`
   - > `dart:ui to package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart`
4. Edit `$project_dir\packages\font-awesome-folder\pubspec.yaml` to use the flutter_web sdk as defined in [the migration guide](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter/versions).
5. Finally do a `flutter pub get` and `pub get`

Of course with this approach we loose the upated versions. Also if font-awesome depends on the something else we have do the same for it. But for time being I find this working for me.

You can check how kevmoo ported provider package to be used with flutter web [here](https://github.com/kevmoo/provider/tree/flutter_web) in this branch.

Answer (score 0):

Pubspec.yaml

```
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

widget build

```
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory("my_div_", (int viewId) {
  DivElement element = DivElement()
    ..id = "reader"
    ..innerHtml = "Hello World";
  return element;
});
```

Scaffold

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Column(children:[ HtmlElementView(viewType: 'my_div')])
```

Comment: The div is not acessible by the id using getElementById on the dom.   The div is inserted on the shadow dom.